# Does AWS SES work with grails Mail plugin 1.0.7?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, grails

I would like to use the AWS SES mail service using SMTP.  I know it works for some versions,  but I haven't gotten it to work for my application yet.  I get a 530 Authentication error.

My question is in three parts:
1.  Does AWS smtp work using Grails 2.3.1 with the Mail 1.0.7 plugin using java 1.7?

2. If it does work,  how does one configure it?
3. If it does work, how can I get more debug information to figure what is wrong?

I've tried every configuration example variant I've come across for this.  My latest is below.  (It's clear I don't really understand the Mail plugin and the Java mail class,  I'm just trying to suss out a working configuration incantation.)

Here is what I have in my config.groovy file:

```
    grails {
       mail {
           host = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
           port = '587'
           username = SMTP AWS username, not IAMS username
           password= SMTP AWS password, not IAMS password 
           props = [ 'mail.debug': true, 
               'mail.smtp.host' : 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
               'mail.smtp.auth': 'true',
               'mail.smtp.starttls.enable': 'true',
               'mail.smtp.port': '587',
               'mail.smtp.starttls.required': 'true',
               'mail.smtp.user' : smtp username from above,
               'mail.smtp.usernme' : smtp username from above,
               'mail.smtp.password': smtp password from above,
               'mail.smtp.socketFactory.port': '587',
               'mail.smtp.socketFactory.class': 
                               'javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory',
                'mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable':'true',
                'mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback': 'false' ]
    }
}
```

I have successfully made direct AWS SES emails using the aws-sdk:1.9.40 plugin, by the way.

I am using the mailService.sendmail code from the Mail plugin. This is unchanged (beyond the hardcoded html text), and works fine when the configuration went to our email server.

```
def resp = mailService.sendMail {
            from replyToEmail
            replyTo replyToEmail
            to user.email
            subject emailSubject
            html "This is the mesage text Mar 20"
        }
```

Any help at all would be most appreciated!!